# Exception nesting/wrapping in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, exception

Is it possible/common-practice to nest/wrap exception (cause) in TypeScript, like in Java?

```
try {
  // do something
} catch (e) {
  throw new MyException("Exception while doing something", e);
}
```

I mean it's probably not a problem to just have a custom ctor for `MyException`, to pass in the `e` arg as `cause`, but what about reporting (printing) the stack traces later on?

Comment: The problem is that you don't know what the type of `e` is. In javascript you can `throw` anything: numbers, strings, Error, arrays, etc. But what you did in your code is completely fine. I requested a feature for [throws clause and typed catch clause](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219) which will make it easier (in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. What if you could do a runtime check, if `e` is an exception and then be able to extract its stack-trace for reporting/printing later (a'la `printStackTrace`)? Is there any such pattern/code in existence?

Comment: @KarolDepka `console.log(e instanceof Error, e.stack);`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the stack trace then you can do this:

```
function normalizeError(e: any): Error {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
        return e;
    }

    return new Error(typeof e === "string" ? e : e.toString());
}
```

And then:

```
try {
    throw [1, "string", true];
}
catch (e) {
    e = normalizeError(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

Which will print something like:

> Error: 1,string,true
>       at normalizeError (:5:12)
>       at :11:9

If you are targetting `es6` then you can extend the `Error` class instead of having this `normalizeError` function, but if you can't target `es6` then you should avoid extending native classes.